# Ruby RhoMobile application development

Tags: ruby, rhomobile, rhodes

I am currently working with **JAVA/J2EE** domain, my project manager asked me to work for an mobile application development with **Ruby RhoMobile**, but I don't have idea about these frameworks other than just go through wiki links.

My question is about the learning curve for this framework with java background and some basic knowledge of CSS, Jquery,Javascript. Is there any **best online training** for Ruby RhoMobile.

Comment: You can check this official docs http://docs.rhomobile.com/en/5.4/guide/api_ruby,  https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/

Comment: Thanks, Looking for some online training, anyway company is going to pay for that, so I can make use of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option is to contact [Tau-Technologies](http://tau-technologies.com/), the primary maintainer of the RhoMobile framework.
They provide the official open source distribution and offer an enterprise grade paid support. For sure they can provide paid training as well as consultancy and customization on the framework.